# How to get number of rows with a unique column value (grouped by an other column value)?

Tags: python, numpy

Consider the following array:

```
x = np.array([[1, 1],[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2],
              [2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 4], [2, 4]])

x
Out[12]: 
array([[1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [2, 3],
       [2, 3],
       [2, 4],
       [2, 4],
       [2, 5],
       [2, 5],
       [2, 5]])
```

How would I get the number of unique column 2 values for each column 1 value?

For example: if it can be done using a function V, then V(x) = [2, 3].

I have implemented this using a for loop. However, it seems more complicated than necessary and takes too much time (when applied to my actual dataset which is much larger than this example).

I am interested in performance and am willing to sacrifice code clarity for speed (although they usually are directly correlated!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`numpy.unique`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) twice:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1, 1],[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2],
              [2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 4], [2, 4]])

# drop duplicates
xx = np.unique(x, axis=0)

# count the first column
values, counts = np.unique(xx[:,0], return_counts=True)

print(values)
print(counts)

# [1, 2]
# [2, 2]
```

Comment: Just curious. How do you approach a problem such as this? Do you try to reverse-engineer the solution?

Comment: @spideyonthego You need to get familiar with the API. It's actually a pretty common problem with numpy and pandas. Once you are familiar with the API and problem pattern, you will find this quite natural.